# Overlay an image in a shiny leaflet observe event

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where I need to add a png image in the instance of an observe event.

I can achieve this outside of Shiny, however, not within an observe function. I assume it has something to do with the map already being rendered?

I've simplified the example (hence just one png), but ideally I want to be able to quickly insert additional png's (i.e radar images)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "80%"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "Action")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that
    # won't need to change dynamically (at least, not unless the
    # entire map is being torn down and recreated).
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = 153.240001, lat = -27.717732, zoom = 7) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addMarkers(lng=153.240001, lat=-27.717732, popup="Mt Stapylton") 
    })
     points2 <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
        TRUE
      }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  # Use the onRender function to add a png
  observe({
    points <- points2()
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
          function(el, x) {
            console.log(this);
            var myMap = this;
            var imageUrl = 'https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
            var imageBounds = [[-25.58,150.71], [-30,155.88]];
            L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(myMap);
          }
        ")
      print("pass")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

### Working outside of leaflet
leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = 153.240001, lat = -27.717732, zoom = 7) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=153.240001, lat=-27.717732, popup="Mt Stapylton") %>%
    htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el, x) {
      console.log(this);
      var myMap = this;
      var imageUrl = 'https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
      var imageBounds = [[-25.58,150.71], [-30,155.88]];
      L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(myMap);
    }
  ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is seems, the `leafletProxy` does not provide a means of accessing the Leaflet Api from the R side.

`onRender` definitely won't work since the whole point of `leafletProxy` is to not rerender the map.

The solution I found was to add a custom event handler on creation of the leaflet, using the `onRender` such that we have access to the Leaflet Api later on.

Using messages is of course kind of restricting, but if the way you want to render images (giving src and bounds) is always the same, it should suffice.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "80%"),
  actionButton("recalc", "Action")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = 153.240001, lat = -27.717732, zoom = 7) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addMarkers(lng=153.240001, lat=-27.717732, popup="Mt Stapylton") %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          var myMap = this;
          // Saving a copy of the overlay to remove it when the next one comes.
          var overlay;

          Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('setOverlay', function(message) {
            if (myMap.hasLayer(overlay)) myMap.removeLayer(overlay);

            overlay = L.imageOverlay(message.src, message.bounds);

            overlay.addTo(myMap);
          });
        }
      ")
  })

  observeEvent(input$recalc, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("setOverlay", list(
      src = 'https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
      bounds = list(list(-25.58,150.71), list(-30,155.88))
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much