# R Shiny: Can't run JS code in a leafletProxy instance

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have shinyapp where I have a leaflet map. I want users to be able to click on the polygons and highlight them right away - while unhighlighting the previous polygon. I successfully do this using some JS code after the leaflet call with `htmlwidgets::onRender`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "80%")

)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% st_transform(4326)
  
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    
    pal <- colorNumeric(
      palette = "Blues",
      domain = data$AREA)
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addPolygons(data = data,
                  fillColor = ~pal(data$AREA), fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
function(el, x) {
    L.control.zoom({
        position: 'topright'
    }).addTo(this);
    var map = this;
    var prevLayerClicked = null;
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.on('click', function(e) {
                if (prevLayerClicked == null) {
                    layer.setStyle({
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    });
                } else if (prevLayerClicked !== null) {
                    layer.setStyle({
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    });
                    prevLayerClicked.setStyle({
                        fillOpacity: 0.5
                    });
                }
                prevLayerClicked = layer;
            })
            .addTo(map);
    });
}
      ")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But my application has a lot of variables and I wanted to be able to change the map using `leafletProxy`. But as soon as I implement some observer with leafletProxy (in that case, I created a dummy button to reset the colors), the highlighting function stops working. Same previous example, but now with the observer:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "80%"),
  actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset Colors")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% st_transform(4326)
  
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    
    pal <- colorNumeric(
      palette = "Blues",
      domain = data$AREA)
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addPolygons(data = data,
                  fillColor = ~pal(data$AREA), fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
function(el, x) {
    L.control.zoom({
        position: 'topright'
    }).addTo(this);
    var map = this;
    var prevLayerClicked = null;
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.on('click', function(e) {
                if (prevLayerClicked == null) {
                    layer.setStyle({
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    });
                } else if (prevLayerClicked !== null) {
                    layer.setStyle({
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    });
                    prevLayerClicked.setStyle({
                        fillOpacity: 0.5
                    });
                }
                prevLayerClicked = layer;
            })
            .addTo(map);
    });
}
      ")
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$reset), {
    
    req(input$reset >= 1)
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = data)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have seen some hints like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846472/leaflet-plugin-and-leafletproxy-with-polylinedecorator-as-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054756/overlay-an-image-in-a-shiny-leaflet-observe-event), but couldn't understand the approaches.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have a similar issue, where I want to add a title to layer checkbox of leaflet map and the only working solution is using onRender which won't work with a proxy map. I don't want to change using a proxy leaflet map just to add a title.