# How to Dynamically Add Markers to a Leaflet Map in Shiny App Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on a Shiny application that includes a Leaflet map. I want to dynamically add markers to the map based on user input, but I'm encountering issues when trying to add these markers using JavaScript within the leafletProxy function.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)  # Needed for onRender

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionButton("add_marker", "Add Marker")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 127.07, lat = 34.45, zoom = 9)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_marker, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
      onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          L.marker([34.50, 127.12]).addTo(this);
        }
      ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this app, I expect a new marker to be added at the coordinates (34.50, 127.12) every time the "Add Marker" button is clicked. However, no new markers appear after the map is initially rendered.

1. Is there a known limitation or issue with using JavaScript in conjunction with leafletProxy to dynamically update a Leaflet map in Shiny?
2. What is the correct way to add markers dynamically to a Leaflet map in a Shiny application using JavaScript?
3. Could there be a timing or scoping issue that prevents the JavaScript code from executing correctly within the leafletProxy function?

I have confirmed that static markers added during the initial rendering (within renderLeaflet) show up as expected. The issue only arises when trying to add markers dynamically after user interaction.

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you have some reason not to use `addMarkers` you could try adapting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054756/overlay-an-image-in-a-shiny-leaflet-observe-event - I have tried myself but without success.

Answer (score 0):

No need of JavaScript:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)  # Needed for onRender

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionButton("add_marker", "Add Marker")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 127.07, lat = 34.45, zoom = 3)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_marker, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% addMarkers(lng = 126, lat = 35, layerId = "xxx")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want to use JavaScript, you don't have to use the proxy:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)  # Needed for onRender

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionButton("add_marker", "Add Marker")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 127.07, lat = 34.45, zoom = 3) %>%
      onRender("function(el, x) {
                 var map = this;
                 $('#add_marker').on('click', function() {
                   L.marker([34.50, 127.12]).addTo(map);
                 });
               }")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I should make it more clear that what I'm actually trying to do is add multiple rotated markers using the js-library. I also want to update the position of these later. Thus, I really want an observe that sends some data that I get in R to the front-end, and triggers some js to add the markers.

Comment: I still don't understand why that can't be done with `addMarkers` - if you include a `layerId` then you can remove them and reposition them again later

Comment: @JarnSchöber I agree with smartse. You don't need JavaScript, it's better/easier to use the proxy and `addMarkers`. Or at least you didn't explain why JavaScript would be needed in your use case. You cannot use `onRender` with the proxy.